# How to view 'data' file which is included by .odb database file?

Tags: database, openoffice.org

I am trying to extract the data from .odb database file. For this, at first I unzipped the .odb file and then tried to read 'data' file came from this unzipped. But I guess there is an encoding problem during the reading process. I get some meaningless symbols. As far I search, this file could be a binary file. By the way, I can not see the extension of the 'data' file.  I wonder how to read file to exract data?

Comment: What stops you from exporting the data to the format of your choice by simply opening the .odb?

Comment: Because when I open 'data' file which is extracted from .odb file looks like ° 0 P Andrew Smith 0 € John McCartney 0 P Ben Dann Table is  1 Andrew Smith  2 John McCartney  3 Ben Dann

Comment: I ment: Open file **in OpenOffice Base**, open your tables and copy the contents!

Comment: You might also want to take a look at HSQL-Database, which drives the internal data file i/a

Comment: I know how to open with Open Office Base. I will try HSQL-DATABASE.

Answer (score 1):

i'm brazilian, and i saw this question without a answer.
i'm python user and i did this:

try to open the file that contains database *.odb

___________________________a file.py________________________

```
import sys, zipfile
myfile = zipfile.ZipFile(yourfile.odb)
listoffiles = myfile.infolist()

for s in listoffiles:

    if s.orig_filename == "database/data":
        print(bh.decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
```

____________________________eof_________________________________

my table is very simple, but it may help.

I've found this jointing parts from several websites.
as you see, an odb file is simply a zipped file that contains a xml file that contains a table information "content.xml" but only table information.
the content of database is in database/data. the values are stored here. you can decode with decode on python.

thanks to http://www.linuxjournal.com/ too, were i found some scripts